# Saving plugin options page

Tags: options

As I understood, default mechanism of saving options on plugin admin settings page (submitting form to options.php) allows to update only WordPress options (get_option, etc). But I have 2 values to save/update:

1) a number - just an option

2) big data from textarea save to text file.

How to make this? I mean where to write PHP code that will handle request after submitting this form?

Comment: Use WordPress settings API to store your data.

Comment: First option I can store in such a way, yes. But the second option is big text file - I need to save it in that way (plain text file)